# What is the meaning of "harmless sensory effect" in Prestidigitation?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

> **sen·so·ry**
>
> relating to sensation or the physical senses; transmitted or perceived by the senses.

Such senses are: *sight, hearing, smell, taste* and *touch*.

Focusing on just these five, here are some examples of harmless sensory effects as I understand it:

Touch: a puff of wind

Hearing: faint musical notes

Smell: odd odor

Taste: a flavour

Sight: such as a shower of sparks

---

So, what is the difference between this and an illusion? What constitutes as a harmless effect? Is a door considered a harmless effect? Is a raincloud considered one? Can my horse have a rainbow nyan-like cat on its fur? Is the sensation of a hand touching someone considered a harmless effect?

I don't understand the spell, can someone please explain to me what is the meaning of "*harmless sensory effect*"?

Comment: Are you asking what constitutes as a "Harmless visual effect" for the purpose of Minor Illusion? It's very unclear.

Comment: it's above all, i don't understand the limits of the spell, visual, thouching,hearing...

Comment: Well, the problem now is that we don't know what is creating the harmless sensory effect. Exactly how it works does change between spell, and for several of your examples, this does matter, as any illusion or similar effect has limits on range, whether it can move around with something, etc. As such, not only do you have too many different questions that you are asking, but you also lack the clarity needed to answer them

Comment: thanks, I had forgotten to write a spell, and about the clarity and quantity of questions, i don't know how to decrease, they all arise from a single doubt, what is the meaning of what harmless sensory effect meaning in Prestidigitation?

Comment: iaminsensible, u are awesome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The effect of Prestidigitation refers to the ability of your illusion to cause harm

> • You create an Instantaneous, **harmless sensory effect**, such as a shower of sparks, a puff of wind, faint musical notes, or an odd odor.

In this context, refers to how the effect you create is harmless. You could, in theory, make a cloud of illusory bees through this spell and they'd be harmless. This isn't explicitly stated, but consider how a real shower of sparks, as per the spell's example, could very easily do real harm to a person's skin and eyes.

As for your examples, explaining why each and every single one would or wouldn't work isn't exactly appropriate to the Stack format, so I'll leave it to your interpretation of [the full rulings on Prestidigitation](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Prestidigitation#content)

Comment: Note that prestidigitation is _not_ an illusion spell; it is Transmutation.  The changes that you make are small, but they are quite real, at least for the duration.

Answer (score 1):

### What's the difference between this and an illusion?

Both *prestidigitation* and illusions create "sensory" effects - that it, they can be sensed or detected.  The difference is that while (most) illusions are not real, *prestidigitation* is in the Transmutation school - it is the magic of changing one thing into another thing.  While the changes it makes are minor, they are quite real, at least for the duration of the spell.

To understand the difference, compare this spell with an illusion cantrip like *[minor illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion)*.

*Minor illusion* can create the 'image' of a torch, but that image can't give off light or heat.  *Prestidigitation*, on the other hand, can't make a torch appear out of nothing - but it can create a real flame that then can ignite a pre-existing candle, torch, or bonfire.  *Minor illusion* can create an image of muddy footprints, but if you try to touch them, your hand passes through them because they are not actually there.  *Prestidigitation* can't create footprints that weren't there before, but it can take a pre-existing object and actually soil it with real mud that you can touch and carry away.

### What is a harmless sensory effect?

"Harmless" literally means they shouldn't be able to cause damage.  The "shower of sparks" may appear bright and even feel hot, but if they land on a creature's skin they cannot cause a point of damage.

I would interpret "harmless" further as meaning they can't impair another creature by creating a mechanically adverse situation or condition.  You might *anger* an NPC by soiling his clothes, but you won't be able to give him disadvantage on his attack rolls from the discomfort of fighting in soiled clothes.  A "puff of wind" in the face of an NPC caster might momentarily distract her in a narrative sense, but it won't force a Concentration save on her spell or give her the Blinded condition for a turn.  You can create a caltrop made from bone (PHB trinket 66), but should someone step on it, it would be crushed rather than reducing their move, and a glass eye (PHB trinket 60) used like a ball bearing would be kicked out of the way rather than provoking a Dex save to avoid falling prone.

Basically, you can make effects that other creatures will notice, and which can influence the roleplay narrative, but not effects that will have prejudicial mechanical results.

### Given these considerations, let's look at your questions

**Is a door considered a harmless effect?**
No, a door is not an effect, it is an item - and far too big to fit in your hand. Not permitted.  Unless you meant just the *image* of a door as visual sensory effect (and thank you to @NobodytheHobgoblin for pointing this out to me).  In that case the door could be full size, but would only last for an instant, so it would be harmless.

**Is a raincloud considered one?**
A floating, cloud-like patch of fog might be a sensory effect (affects vision), but if it filled a square it would have to be largely transparent.  If it imposed the 'obscured' condition, that would not be considered 'harmless' (as it would negatively impact Perception checks), but as a sensory effect it would likely not last long enough to do so anyway.

**Can my horse have a rainbow nyan-like cat on its fur?**
"You make **a** color...appear on...a surface for 1 hour."  One color, not many.  You could make your horse into [a horse of a different color](https://i.pinimg.com/474x/fc/be/1d/fcbe1d0d6b1123be5d63e2441a1c96b9.jpg), but not a [rainbow unicorn](https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/231-2319538_rainbow-unicorn-png-rainbow-my-little-pony-unicorn.png) over all its coat, mane, and tail.  Alternately, you could make a *small* "mark or symbol" of [nyan cat](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2Fiask892buh9y.jpg%3Fwidth%3D640%26crop%3Dsmart%26auto%3Dwebp%26s%3Da73260c432f943c19c2aba9320bd321428eeb2f1) appear on some part of your horse - although it is unclear whether the mark could be multicolored if it was small enough.

**Is the sensation of a hand touching someone considered a harmless effect?**
The sensation of disembodied [fingertips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExuL2SbTIEw&t=10s) running along one's forearm would be decidedly *creepy*, but within the power of the spell.  The sensation could not provoke disadvantage on an attack roll or skill check, or force a Concentration save, however, as it would then not be "harmless".

Comment: Dying her eyes to match her gown would be *thaumaturgy* though, and only for a minute.

Comment: The sensory effect does not need to fit in your hand, that's the trinket. +1 for the rest if this.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Right, but calling a door a 'sensory effect' so that you can make it larger than your hand does not change the fact that it is **not** a sensory effect; it is an item with physical tangibility.  Such things must be hand-sized, whether you call them trinkets or not.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Ah, now that I read _your_ answer, I see that you are taking OP's "door" to mean just the image (visual sensory effect) of a door, not an actual door.  In this case, yes, it would not have to fit in one's hand.  I don't think it is clear what kind of door OP means, but after a re-read of their question, I think you are right that they probably mean an image.

Comment: Yes, my impression was that they wanted to understand where the boundary of visual effects vs images is, because otherwise, you never would pick *minor illusion*, if a visual sensory *prestidigitation* effect could do the same, and then some other stuff, too. I wouldn't even have posted an answer but messed up commenting on mobile, and posted my comment as an answer first. So I thought I better overwrite it with something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

### The sensory effect only lasts for an instant

Here is the effect in question from *[Prestidigitation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation)*:

> - You create an **instantaneous, harmless sensory effect**, such as a shower of sparks, a puff of wind, faint musi­cal notes, or an odd odor.

The spell has a duration of *up to an hour*, and each effect tells you how long it will last.

The harmless, sensory effect is described as ***instantaneous***, that is, is only happens for a fleeting instance. Even if you could create a door as a visual effect, it would briefly appear, then vanish. So you cannot use it to imitate the *minor illusion* spell, that can create longer lasting images of objects. Given the examples, the effect likely cannot be an object to begin with, but is something that is happening, like sparks, motes of light, a bit of twirling colorful glitter etc.

You might be able to create some of the other items you ask about with other options of *prestidigitation*, but none of the lasting ones with this option. The exception is the feeling of  fingers  briefly touching someone - that can both be instantaneous, and is harmless in itself.